# Altering multiple rows into a model with one submit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, models

I'm trying to put together a rails site that uses a number of models. One is a model called requests that takes in a couple pieces of information associated with essentially a single purchase. The other is a model that collects a number of the requests together under one "order" id.

The problem is, I want the view associated with request to allow for multiple request entries with one submission, and I can't figure that out. As I've currently got it, someone can submit a single request for a single "cut", but I want them to enter a number of requests for a number of cuts on a single page, with a single submission.

My current _form document associated with my view is:

```
<%= form_for(@request) do |f*| %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :cut %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :cut %>
  </div>
   <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :lbs %><br />
    <%= f.number_field :lbs %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :notes %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :notes %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label "Order ID" %><br />
    <%= f.number_field :order_id %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :status %><br />
    <%= f.number_field :status %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>

<% end %>
```

Any idea how I can create a form document that allows me to enter several new 'rows' of requests with one submit? Or how to ensure they all have the same order-id?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try these screencasts from Ryanb, I think they'll get you a long way.

- http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1
- http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2

Comment: Thanks! I'm checking those out right now. RailsCasts says that there's a more up-to-date version of the cast (that I can access for the $9/month subscription price) and I was wondering if you knew if I'd need those, or if the ones you linked me to should be just fine for Rails 3.

Comment: It depends how good you are ;) Seriously, the methodology hasn't changed that much so you should be able to figure it out I think. And if not you can always come back here with specific issues.